# How or when the amount get deducted or transferred from the buyers paypal account

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, e-commerce, virtuemart

How or when the amount get deducted or transferred from the buyers paypal account to the shop owner's account via Virtuemart in Joomla 1.5? I created the paypal sandbox test account but doesn't seems to deduct the amount of item(s) I bought?

If there's anything unclear please let me so I can explain further.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: How is this programming related? Please edit your question; adding the following points may get you better answers: 1. What are you trying to accomplish? 2. What have you tried so far? 3. What results did you get? 4. How did that differ from the results you were expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps VirtueMart changes inventory only when it receives an IPN (instant payment notification) from PayPal about a successful transaction? PayPal has an IPN simulator - try using that. Also, you can login to your test business account and approve the transaction from there - this also sends an IPN back to store.